# Compare array element to hash key and append hash value to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, control-flow

```
SCORECARD = {
   "1" => 40,
   "2" => 100,
   "3" => 300,
   "4" => 1200
}


def get_score(arr)
  
   score_base = []
  
   #level = getPoints(arr) / 10
   score_base = calculateScore(arr)

end

def getPoints(points)
    points.inject(0) do |sum, point|
       sum + point
    end
end


def calculateScore(lines)
    score_base = []  
    lines.each do |line|
  
        SCORECARD.each do |key, value|
  
            if line == key
                score_base << value
            end
            score_base
        end
     end
end
  

describe "Basic tests" do
  Test.assert_equals(get_score([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 1640)
  Test.assert_equals(get_score([0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2]), 620)
  Test.assert_equals(get_score([2, 0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3]), 3300)
end

describe "Special tests" do
  Test.assert_equals(get_score([0]), 0)
  Test.assert_equals(get_score([]), 0)
end

Test Results:
Basic tests
Expected: 1640, instead got: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Expected: 620, instead got: [0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2]
Expected: 3300, instead got: [2, 0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3]
STDERR
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:60:in `block in describe': Expected: 1640, instead got: [0, 
1, 2, 3, 4] (Test::Error)
    from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:46:in `measure'
    from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:51:in `describe'
    from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:202:in `describe'
    from main.rb:46:in `<main>'
```

PROBLEM: I need assistance with debugging the `calculateScore` method. Essentially, I would like to iterate through the lines array and the `SCORECARD` hash, then check if the current line is equal to a hash key, and finally push the value of the matched key into the `score_base` array.

Once I have pushed all values into the `score_base` array, I plan to multiply each element within the `score_base` array by the user's current level, then I will sum all the elements into `totalScore`.

The output seems to only return the elements within the lines array. Can someone shed some light on what is happening?

EDIT: MY SOLUTION TO PROBLEM

````
```
SCORECARD = {
  "1" => 40,
  "2" => 100,
  "3" => 300,
  "4" => 1200
}

def get_score(arr)
  totalScore = multiplyByLevel(arr)
end

def calculateScore(line)
  score_base = []
  
   score_base.push SCORECARD.fetch(line.to_s, 0)  
   score_base.reduce(:+)
end

def multiplyByLevel(points)
  experience = 1.0
  level = 0
  totalScore = 0
  
  points.each do |point|
   
    experience = experience.round(1) + (point.to_f / 10)
  
    if level < 2
      totalScore = totalScore + (1 * calculateScore(point))
    elsif level >= 2
      totalScore = totalScore + (level.round(1) * calculateScore(point))
    else
      print "Outside loop, level is #{level}"
    end
    level = experience.to_i
    
  end  
  
  totalScore
end
```
````

EDIT: IN RESPONSE TO BOBRODES FEEDBACK: REFACTORING CALCULATESCORE METHOD

````
```
def calculateScore(lines)
  score_base = []
  lines.map {|line| score_base << SCORECARD[line.to_s]}
  score_base.compact
end
#=> [40,100,300,1200]
```
````

Comment: `def get_score(arr);
   arr.sum{|el| SCORECARD[el].to_i };
end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic problem is that `#each` always returns the receiver (the *receiver* is whatever is to the left of `.each`). Let's look at your code:

```
def calculateScore(lines)
  score_base = []  
  lines.each do |line|
    SCORECARD.each do |key, value|
      if line == key
        score_base << value
      end
      score_base
    end # << returns SCORECARD
  end # << returns lines
end
```

So, you need to put `score_base` here:

```
def calculateScore(lines)
  score_base = []  
  lines.each do |line|
    SCORECARD.each do |key, value|
      if line == key
        score_base << value
      end
    end # << returns SCORECARD
  end # << returns lines
  score_base
end
```

This is an explanation of the first part of steenslag's answer, but I'd also look at the rest of his advice.

Your code has another problem. The keys in `SCORECARD` are strings, while the values in your test inputs for `lines` are integers. So, once you fix the problem you asked about, you will always get an empty array for your result.

But your code also has a bigger problem, which is that you can use `#map` to get what you want with one simple line of code! You could certainly condense your code a good deal while still using `#each`, but `#map` is designed to transform values while iterating through them, and `#each` is designed to just iterate through them. You want to transform your values (from `SCORECARD` keys to `SCORECARD` values), so `#map` is the simplest way to go.

I don't want to take away all the fun and do it for you, so here's a simple example of `#map`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map { |num| num + 1 } #=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

See if you can take that idea with your test input `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and return `[nil, 40, 100, 300, 1200]`. Then, work out how to add all those together (there's a method to remove `nil` values that you will find helpful) and you'll have your one-liner.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Bob. I continued to work on the problem after making my initial post and worked out a solution (new solution above). However, I decided to attempt your challenge as well.

Here is what I came up with:

def calculateScore(lines)
  score_base = []
  lines.map {|line| score_base << SCORECARD[line.to_s]}
  score_base.compact
end
#=> [40, 100, 300, 1200]

Comment: @MrSandman98765 Coming along! You still have two things to look at. First, you don't need the `score_base` variable at all. You're still thinking in terms of `#each`. Look at my `#map` example, and understand that if this were in a method all by itself, it would return the result to anything that called the method. The other thing is that you still want to sum the result (good job finding `#compact`, you can't sum nil values). So, work out a way to get rid of your superfluous `score_base`, tack a method that sums the result onto `#compact`, and you'll have your one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

The `each` method of an Array returns the Array itself (from the docs: "each {|item| block} → ary") So that is what you get. Look into [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map). Note that the `getPoints` method is not actually used, so no sum is calculated

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, steenslag!